# How to add proxy to quickstart.py-python

Tags: python, gmail-api

I execute quickstart.py according to the steps of the tutorial, and he will report an error. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the proxy in my place, so I especially want to know how to add my proxy to quickstart.py and how to add it is correct. The error message is as follows, hope to answer, thank you!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 506, in _connect_tls_proxy
    ssl_context=ssl_context,
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 450, in ssl_wrap_socket
    sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "D:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "D:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "D:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/2021-0/Project/eliis_arno/RpaChangeOrder/test/quickstart.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/2021-0/Project/eliis_arno/RpaChangeOrder/test/quickstart.py", line 28, in main
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 479, in run_local_server
    self.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 288, in fetch_token
    return self.oauth2session.fetch_token(self.client_config["token_uri"], **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 344, in fetch_token
    **request_kwargs
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 516, in request
    method, url, headers=headers, data=data, **kwargs
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error')))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What tutorial are you talking about? What is the code that triggers this error?